# I need to block the POP3 DELE Message by IPtables - Linux

Tags: linux, email, iptables, postfix, dovecot

I installed the iRedMail (Postfix, Dovecot, ....) and create Mailboxes for Users. But I hanged in the Deletion Request.

I want to prevent vUsers (that have MAilboxes) from deleting the eMails (Business Request).

Some Searches said to make ACL on the Maildir, bit I think that this solution will make problems in the Service User during the Deletion.

So I think that the solution may come from another way, from the IPtables, I want to block the POP3 DELE Request before entering the Server. I tried but failed.

Any Help in that (in IPtables Configurations or another Solution)... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The iptables strategy is not the appropiate one IMHO, because you take for granted that the `DELE` command will be always sent as a whole in the same TCP packet, when it doesn't need to and the packet might be split into several packets. So that would result in some messages blocked and some not.

I'd consider using the 'lazy expunge' plugin for Dovecot, which makes the "deleted" e-mails be moved actually to a different folder, but never deleted (or deleted only when the administrator configure the action). I think that is the cleanest way of achieving this.

You can find more info [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Lazyexpunge).

Comment: I believe that the IPtables can match on a string found in the Packet Payload, I blocked before the Torrent Traffic by IPtables String options, without assigning any blocked Port Number.

Comment: But I am interested in doing the "Lazy expunge", so I will search and return to you back ISA... Thanks.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that the whole command won't be sent in the same packet necessarily. For example, the command might be sent as `POP3 D` at the end of a TCP packet and the rest of the packet be splitted into another with content `ELE`, which wouldn't match your rule. Anyways, the plugin approach is quite cleaner to me than the iptables way.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but if you found the POP3 DELE Payload Format, kindly add comment.